# How can I align the column headers with the values in each column when importing a csv into docx as a table?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, ms-word, python-docx

How can I align the column headers with the values in each column when importing this csv into docx as a table?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Target':['Targetttt','Targetttttttttttttttttt'],
    'Something': ['2.037','2.099'],
    'Something_long': ['3.123','4.123'],
    'Something _even_longer': ['1.123','1.234']
})
df

df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\TABLE.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index = False)

import docx 
import csv

doc = docx.Document()

with open('TABLE.csv', newline='') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f) 

    csv_headers = next(csv_reader)
    csv_cols = len(csv_headers)

    table = doc.add_table(rows=2, cols=csv_cols)
    hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells

    for i in range(csv_cols):
        hdr_cells[i].text = csv_headers[i]

    for row in csv_reader:
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
        for i in range(csv_cols):
            row_cells[i].text = row[i]

doc.add_page_break()
doc.save("data.docx")
```

dataframe looks like this:

```
    Target            Something Something_long  Something _even_longer
0   Targetttt         2.037     3.123           1.123
1   Targetttttttttttt 2.099     4.123           1.234
```

When exporting the csv into word, the table loses it's formatting and the values in the columns don't align in each column anymore since the length of characters of each value differs.

Comment: What kind of alignment did you have in mind? Typically a heading and the numeric values below it are both right-aligned to give a reasonable visual, like the heading and its values all share a common vertical right-side boundary.

Comment: I would like to do a left align if possible@scanny

Comment: I would be ok with right align as well is that's easier... The way the code is right now I have no alignment. @scanny

Answer (score 0):

For each cell, just align its first paragraph the way you want:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

cell.paragraphs[0].paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
# --- or .RIGHT or .CENTER if you like ---
```

You might want to align different blocks of cells differently, like maybe you want the row headings left-aligned, which is typical in table-layout.

A utility function might be handy:

```
def align_cell(cell, alignment):
    for p in cell.paragraphs:
        p.paragraph_format.alignment = alignment
```

such that you can just call:

```
align_cell(cell, WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT)
```

which is a little more compact.